# How can I orient particles on a round object?

Tags: objects, particles, hair

*This is a question, that came up whilst working on a scientific representation of a cell membrane.*

In the following image you can see the particle system applied to a plane:

[image]

What I now want to do is to apply that particle system to a cylinder or circular object, which will show the cross-section of a vesicle. The particles should therefore all face outwards from the origin point of the circle. In the Rotation menu of the particle system there is no option for the particle to be orientated 90° away from the surface. Here is a bad sketch of how it should look.

[image]

**Q:** How can I orient particles on a round object?

Comment: Set Hair as particle type.
Render > Render as > choose Object.
Render > Object > choose Instance Object.
Render > Object >  check Object Rotation.
Rotate particle object by 90deg on y axis

Comment: are you not looking for Normals?

Comment: "Render > Object > check Object Rotation" was what I was missing. thanks for the quick help